wsl 2 fail to launch second Distro - windows 11 22H2
install of second  wsl distro - the second distro i not listed and cannot be lunched.
Checking the created folder on AppData\Local\Packages\ i see the VHDX file is not created
system is windows 11 Pro 22H2
wsl version
WSL version: 2.1.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.146.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.60
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2070

Install using command line passes without error also reported as installed.

first distro working


Reboot PC/WSL
Update WSL/PowerShell/Windows
Run as Administrator
Installed from File or from web

